# How to add the Terms and Conditions to custom form,not using any profile 2 or webform module?

Tags: 7, forms

How to add the Terms and Conditions to custom form? 
 i have made a module and willing to add a "read me / terms and conditions " type of thing to my form .

Whole code can be seen here , just dont wanted to write it again .
[Custom module error, does'nt show on the page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/custom-module-error-doesnt-show-on-the-page)

Please suggest.

Comment: @kantu checkbox that hides a textarea with states property is what you mean? But if check box is ticked then that displays the text area with conditions text but then how to accept these conditions . With the checkbox we can toggle the textarea but which checkbox will refer to acceptance or agreeing to terms and conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another element to the form like so:

```
$form['terms'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Terms & Conditions'),
  '#prefix' => "<p>Your terms go here</p>",
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

That will just stick the text before the checkbox, and then use CSS to position it however you want.

You might also want to put a validate hook in there and remove the `#required` attribute so you can write your own text in the `form_set_error`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions,but through little research i came to find out that we have a module called as Legal for adding terms and condtions http://drupal.org/project/legal

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Legal](https://www.drupal.org/project/legal) module

> Displays your Terms & Conditions to users who want to register, and requires that they accept the T&C before their registration is accepted.