# How to create a module with forms?

Tags: 7

I am little stuck with creating a module for drupal.

I would like to show users a link: "Create", then to take them to a page where will be forms.

Can someone post little piece of code so i could see how to implement other...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

One of the best way to learn how to do develop various common tasks is with [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module.

Check especially the `form_example` module which has all necessary instructions and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

i have made a form via module u may have a look

[Custom module error, does'nt show on the page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/custom-module-error-doesnt-show-on-the-page)

For any queries feel free to ask.
Thanks